# An error occurred in Sitecore 8.1 Experience Editor

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore8.1, experience-editor

I have set up a project in Sitecore 8.1 MVC using Glass mapper v4. I opened the Home page in Experience Editor I got following error:

[image]

Did I miss something.

Thanks

Comment: Sometimes people have way too much faith in others. You wrote that you have error "An error occured" and you think we can in some magical way read in your computer's mind and help you with your issue. Trust me, it will be much easier if you check Sitecore logs and add stack trace to your question. Maybe even the question will not be necessary cause the stack trace would tell you where the issue is...

Comment: Just to be fair, he could be a beginner and not even know how to use F12 or developer tools to even start there. He is just looking for some guiding lights to point him in the right direction because he obviously does not know where to look.  Otherwise he wouldn't ask such a seemingly amateur question (no offense to thread starter)

Comment: actaully if I poen page editor in sitecore vanilla instance it's doesn't show me this error but getting this error on the project team have develop.
don't know from where to start debugging.I though this is general error if someone has faced earlier

Comment: I have gone through the log file and found this error: You cannot save a class that does not contain a property that represents the item ID. Ensure that at least one property has been marked to contain the Sitecore ID. Type: Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Link
after that I added `virtual Guid Id` field in all model classes but still getting the same error

Comment: Sukhi please post your model.

Comment: actually there are near about 10-12 model classes do I post all classess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great finally problem solved actually it was dll version issue. I replace the existing ContentSearch dll with version 4.1 and it's solved

Thanks